# Internal Server Error when Page Doesn't Exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've just realised that if you were to manually type in the URL bar a page that doesn't exist on my site, the site responds with an Internal Server Error.

Should it not be a 404 page not found?

My site is http://www.cristianrgreco.com, for example http://www.cristianrgreco.com/example will return a server error.

This is an error I frequently encountered when toying with .htaccess files so I have posted mine below.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks 

# Add WWW to URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cristianrgreco\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cristianrgreco.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Remove trailing slashes from end of URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.cristianrgreco\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

# Rewrite article URLs
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$1

# Remove file extension from PHP files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might try [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before, the problem is this line

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]`

replacing it with `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]` seems todo the trick. the enclosing brackets signify that anything that is matched will be remembered by the RewriteRule. Inside the brackets, it says `“I’d like one or more characters that aren’t a dot”.`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   Options +Indexes
   RewriteEngine On
   # Add WWW to URL
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cristianrgreco\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.cristianrgreco.com/$1 [L,R=301]

   # Remove trailing slashes from end of URL
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.cristianrgreco\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

   # Rewrite article URLs
   RewriteRule ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ articles.php?article=$1

   # Remove file extension from PHP files
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, would never have figured that out myself. Thanks so much!